# Two identical dishes - how do I adjust temp and time for two 9x13 pans instead of just one?

Tags: baking

Two identical dishes - how do I adjust temp and time for two 9x13 pans instead of just one? It calls for one being baked at 350 for 40-45 minutes.

Comment: Are we talking about double the amount in the original container size, or the original recipe divided into two smaller containers?

Comment: I needed two identical casseroles.  Both are in 9X13 pans.  One is supposed to bake for 40-45 minutes at 350 degrees.  I am going to put ad additional identical recipe and pan in the oven at the same time.  I just don't know if I go ahead and cook two according to the directions to cook one or if I need to change the time and temp.  Thank you in advance for your response!

Answer (score 3):

Likely no adjustment is necessary if they fit in your oven with good circulation.  If it is a tight fit, you might want to add a few minutes, and/or rotate them halfway through the cooking.  Your best approach is to simply measure the temperature of your product around the 45 minute mark and adjust from there.